# RecyclerView - dynamic height without shifting elements

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, kotlin

What I need:

[image: here]

I tried doing this using a `RecyclerView` that sets the height of the item dynamically based on the model. I am using

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teacher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/room"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/teacher"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1976D2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:lines="1" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter-code:

```
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SampleViewHolders {
    val layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.rv_grid, null)
    layoutView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
        override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
            val lp = layoutView.getLayoutParams()
            if (lp is StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
                val sglp = lp as StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
                when (viewType) {
                    1 -> sglp.isFullSpan = false
                    2 -> {
                        sglp.height = layoutView.height * 2;
                        layoutView.refreshDrawableState();
                    }
                    3 -> sglp.height = layoutView.height * 3;
                }
                layoutView.setLayoutParams(sglp)
                val lm = (parent as RecyclerView).layoutManager as StaggeredGridLayoutManager
                lm.invalidateSpanAssignments()
            }
            layoutView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
            return true
        }
    })
    return ViewHolder(layoutView)
}
```

Where it does multiplies with the number of hours the meeting takes.

The problem is that if there is a one-hour meeting after a 2-hour meeting, it gets shifted to the next day.

See:

**With 2-hour meetings:**

[image]

**With 1-hour meetings:**

[image]

How can I fix this in the adapter/how can I adapt the height without shifting the elements?

Comment: https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I haven't found this in my research.

Comment: just to point out that the week-view github link is done using a custom view and not recycler view

Answer (score 0):

Import the library into your project.
Grab via maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.alamkanak</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-week-view</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.6</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Grab via gradle

```
compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'
```

Add WeekView in your xml layout.

```
<com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView
        android:id="@+id/weekView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:eventTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:textSize="12sp"
        app:hourHeight="60dp"
        app:headerColumnPadding="8dp"
        app:headerColumnTextColor="#8f000000"
        app:headerRowPadding="12dp"
        app:columnGap="8dp"
        app:noOfVisibleDays="3"
        app:headerRowBackgroundColor="#ffefefef"
        app:dayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
        app:todayBackgroundColor="#1848adff"
        app:headerColumnBackground="#ffffffff"/>
```

Write the following code in your java file.

/

```
/ Get a reference for the week view in the layout.
mWeekView = (WeekView) findViewById(R.id.weekView);

// Set an action when any event is clicked.
mWeekView.setOnEventClickListener(mEventClickListener);

// The week view has infinite scrolling horizontally. We have to provide the events of a
// month every time the month changes on the week view.
mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(mMonthChangeListener);

// Set long press listener for events.
mWeekView.setEventLongPressListener(mEventLongPressListener);
```

Implement WeekView.MonthChangeListener, WeekView.EventClickListener, WeekView.EventLongPressListener according to your need.

Provide the events for the WeekView in WeekView.MonthChangeListener.onMonthChange() callback. Please remember that the calendar pre-loads events of three consecutive months to enable lag-free scrolling.

```
MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener mMonthChangeListener = new MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public List<WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
        // Populate the week view with some events.
        List<WeekViewEvent> events = getEvents(newYear, newMonth);
        return events;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is not an answer the question asks about recyclerview and you are pointing  him to a custom view